# jPBM 5.4 extend BPMN 2.0 Task

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

In the course of my Master's thesis, I need to extend the definition of the rule task with a new property. I would use the definition (which is given by the BPMN 2.0 standard). For this I need to implement the classes "Definition", "ExtensionDefinition" and "ExtensionAttributeDefinition".

My problem:
Where to I put the implemented classes? Of course I cannot start in the main-method because the user needs the property during the modeling of the process.

I'm thankful for any help.

Greetings
Katharina

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to extend the BPMN2 support inside jBPM right? You first need to check if jBPM is not defining those elements. After that you will need to extend the jbpm-bpmn2 module with those features and then probably the process designer to allow the process designer to add those extension elements. 
I wanna make sure that I'm understanding your requirements in the right way.

I will strongly recommend you to get in contact with us (jbpm team) in order to coordinate your work, so it can be included as part of the project when its done. As a first step I will recommend you to check the jbpm-bpmn2 project which defines all the supported structures.

Regards

Comment: Hello Salaboy, thank you for your answer. What I need is a way to extend the flow elemtents and the artefacts with a new attribute. With this attribute I would, with the help of Drools rules, validate the information flow. My current approach: writing an jBPMN 2.0 extension XML schema which defines the missing attributes for the flow elements and the artefacts. Now it should be possible to define Drools rules doing flow desicions based on these new attributes. - My questions see next comment :) -

Comment: My question is how does jBPM support self-defined BPMN extensions? Does jBPM 6.1 support background Drools rules, because I didn't get it to work with this version (now I use Version 5.4)? Thank you in advanced, Katharina